# WordPress: How to address a icon within a input field (date picker) generated by contact form 7?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I feel like a beginner. I just don't manage to address the datepicker icon with CSS. There is simply nothing for this in the DOM. I've already tried a few approaches, but without success.

I use the WordPress theme ["Bridge"](https://bridgelanding.qodeinteractive.com/) and have already looked for this icon in the Qode Options. Unfortunately I can't find anything.

I copied this out of the chrome dev tools. It is practically the complete container in which the datepicker is located. No: :before, :after or similar to be found:

```
<div class="column1">
   <div class="column_inner">
      <div class="qode-cf-date-holder">
          <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-date">
              <input type="date" name="your-date" value="2020-10-17" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date required" min="2020-10-17" max="2035-12-31" aria-invalid="false">
          </span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I just want to set the cursor to pointer :D. The icon is placed inside the input element (but I can't see how) that gets generated by [contact form 7](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Here is a screenshot of the input field:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). Unfortunately, currently the input fields in html do not support this feature.

But you can use this feature in the field's parent. Your code looks something like this. (If you use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)).

```css
.qode-cf-date-holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.qode-cf-date-holder:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  content: '\f073';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

You can style Pseudo-Elements almost like any other DOM Element, for example you can assign an image to its background.

Comment: Not very clean (because I can't remove the old icon) but it works :), thanks :)

Comment: Good job. You can find the icon with the **inspect element** and assign the `display: none` style to it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the icon with inspect element :D

Answer (score 0):

Without a visual reference a bit hard to answer but have you tried:

```
input[name="your-date"] {
  //css here
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that and many similar approaches. Unfortunately without success. I added a picture. The part of the DOM is already in my question.

Comment: yeah I looked at it on a fresh WP install and it is strange. Im thinking it's a jquery library thing maybe, for sure jquery is handling this. If you change input type from date to text in dev tools you can see it disappear. This hints to something but not sure what. You can find a date picker plugin that would probably give you more control maybe.